# Initialized in Controller, Null in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm creating a form and passing the `FormView` to the template

```php
$form = $this->createForm('my_user_form', $user);
die(get_class($form->createView()));
return $this->render('MyBundle::edit.html.twig', array(
    'form', $form->createView()
));
```

The `die()` gives me

> Symfony\Component\Form\FormView

The `dump()` (from the template)

```
{{ dump(form) }}
```

gives me

> null

How can this be explained ?

Comment: You meant to set an index like: "form" => $form->createView() ?

Comment: That's indeed what I meant :) The kind of thing you spend hours on... Thx

Answer (score 0):

Thx again to @OIS, I was meaning

```
return $this->render('MyBundle::edit.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
));
```

instead of

```
return $this->render('MyBundle::edit.html.twig', array(
    'form', $form->createView()
));
```